# How to render a <Route/> from react-route-dom using a object and not a component / function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a list of objects, that has an `path`, a `name` and a React `component` as attributes. When I iterate over the list of objects, getting each object and rendering a `<Route key={indice} path={route.path} name={route.name} component={route.component}/>` component, I receive a warning:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.
          in Route (at DefaultLayout.js:158)
          in DefaultLayout (created by Context.Consumer)
          in Connect(DefaultLayout) (created by Route)
          in Route (at DefaultLayout.test.js:22)
          in PersistGate (at DefaultLayout.test.js:21)
          in Provider (at DefaultLayout.test.js:20)
          in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
          in BrowserRouter (at DefaultLayout.test.js:19)
```

I had already tried to nest the `route.component` in a way that it acts like a `<Component />`, but this approach was a little complex when it communicates with other components. Obviously I had tried to nest the component in a arrow function `() => (route.component)`, but I still receiving the warning.

The approach I had tried (the 'complex' one):

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return this.loggedIn
          ? <Component {...props} />
          : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
      }}
    />
)
```

I expect to render a `<Route />` that receives a component `[{component: Dashboard}]`, without no warnings.

Comment: How does your Array object look like when you map over them. What I want to know is how route.Component is stored in your data

Comment: `[{name: path: component:}, {name: path: component:}, {name: path: component:}]`, this is in a separated file, then I import the object to the file I want ot use it. The flow is: routes.js import the components and generates a list of object, a random component import the list present in routes.js and iterate over the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use  component as below:

```
<Route
      key={index}
      path={route.path}
      exact={route.exact}
      name={route.name}
      render={props => (
           <route.component {...props} />
      )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function isLoggin() {
    return this.loggedIn ? true : false;
}

function PrivateRoute ({component: Component, ...rest}) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => isLoggin()
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
    />
  )
}

<BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: This is basically what I'm doing, but you had transformed logged in in a function...